# How to resign before starting?

Tags: resignation, contracts

In the last one year I have been continuously looking for jobs, applying to many roles that suit me. Recently I landed a job offer X, and since this was the only one I accepted it, signed the contract but the day I signed I got another job offer Y which is paying me really handsome amount.

After reconsidering my situation and the education loan I took, Y is of course better with a brand name and other benefits which X did not offer.

I signed the contract to start in the next week but I think it would be unethical (or is it?) to start the job get all the trainings and then resign

I have decided to join Y how do I communicate this with X?

Comment: What is stated in your contract with X? Terms of resignation etc?

Comment: During probation, either party can terminate the contract with one week of notice

Comment: I personally think it would be unethical to start the job, be trained up, and have absolutely no intention of putting your training to use for the company that trained you.

Comment: **Do nothing until you have a contract from Y**

Comment: I agree with what @Smock is saying. Don't tell them. I had a friend who did similar thing and company Y decided to ghost him. then he lost both X and Y offers. and had to wait a while to find a new job

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell them immediately . They will not be happy about this, but it makes absolutely no sense to start there and resign right away. It's a lot of work to get a new employee into the system and it's better that you don't start at all.

You should have told them as soon as you decided to go with Y. The earlier they know, the easier it for them to deal with this and the less bridges you are burning.

They will not be happy about it so the best you can do is to minimize their amount of unhappiness.

Comment: I haven't received a contract from Y. It's just an email acceptance that I have given. How does that change the situation

Comment: @Liger How would you be sure that Y is going to pay you `handsome amount` without an offer and contract in sight? I wouldn't make any decision before I see the offer from Y.

Comment: I agree with this one, and also point out that you should have a formal offer from Y before communicating X to secure your position. I had a similar situation happening with me recently: I was in 2 selections (one for the position I am now and one for another position I was recommended for by a friend). I notified both companies that I was in another selection process and when I got the offer from company 1, I immediately called company 2 - and my friend - to cancel the interview I was going to do on the following day (the offer from 1 was better than anything 2 could put on the table)

Comment: Y said I'll get the contract today by COB. As soon as I get a formal contract it's best to communicate with X

Answer (score 1):

> I have decided to join Y how do I communicate this with X?

Resign, giving the contractual notice of a week. Make sure you do this within the probation period and that you have got a signed contract for the job at Y (not just an offer of employment). When asked for a start date at Y, make sure its later than 1 week.

Your resignation letter should say something like "Thank you very much for the opportunity, but on further reflection, I have decided that I'm not a good fit for this role".